# php surf along html DOM callbacking node plain text contents

Tags: php, html, nested

**Scenario**:

I need to apply a php function to the plain text contained inside HTML tags, and show the result, maintaining the original tags (with their original attributes).

**Visualize**:

Take this:

```
<p>Some text here pointing to the <a href="#">moon</a> and that's it</p>
```

Return this:

```
<p>
phpFunction('Some text here pointing to the ')
<a href="#">phpFunction('moon')</a>
phpFunction(' and that\'s it')
</p>
```

**What I should do**:

Use a PHP html parser (instead of using regexp) and iterate over every tag, applying the callback to the node text content.

**Problem**:

If I have, for example, an `<a>` tag inside a `<p>` tag, the text content of the parent `<p>` tag would consist of two different plain text parts, which the php callback should considerate as separate.

**Question**:

How should I approach this in a clean and smooth way?

Thanks for your time, all the best.

Comment: Have you seen Zend Dom Query? When you iterate over an element just check if it contains other tags, if so call your method recursively.

Comment: @divix Thanks for your answer. I never used ZF before. Do you think it is efficient to get into a Framework just for this functionality? (Or do you recommend completely jumping into ZF for all my projects? Why?)

Comment: You can use a specific Zend class independent, you don't need to include a whole framework, that's why ZF is so great. Alternativly you can use less powerful external DOM library: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net

Comment: @divix Thank you for the help and the good references. Have a great day.

Comment: No worries man, glad to help.

Comment: @divix I added an alternative approach, without ZF/phpSimpleDOM. Thanks again, stay cool. [See answer below]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I decided to use regex instead of including an external library.

**For the sake of simplicity**:

```
$expectedOutput = preg_replace_callback(
'/>(.*)</U',
function ($withstuff) {
return '>'.doStuff($withStuff).' <';
},
$fromInput
);
```

This will look for everything between `>` and `<`, which is, indeed, what I was looking for.

Of course any suggestion/comment is still welcome.

Peace.